# Heroku bash cannot find php command

Tags: php, windows, laravel, heroku, heroku-cli

I wanted to publish Laravel App on Heroku today but Heroku bash couldn't find php command.

I update database details in `config/database.php` and next want to run migration but when i go to `heroku run bash` and `php artisan migrate --app myappname` I only see `bash: php: command not found`

I'm on Windows10.

Comment: Make sure you installed composer and point it to your php.exe

Comment: Problem solved. In `composer.json` i had ~7.1.3 version of PHP, after change to `"php": "~7.3.0"` and `git push heroku master` it start work

Comment: @Chris Some folks build the migration step into their Heroku deployment, but it's pretty common to push a deploy then do the migration through `heroku run bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. In composer.json i had ~7.1.3 version of PHP, after change to "php": "~7.3.0" and git push heroku master it start work